# OpenGL, wait for output to be displayed on screen

Tags: opengl, jogl, glreadpixels

I'm trying to draw a few images on a GLWindow and then after they've been drawn, read them into a bytebuffer. The displaying part works fine and the image reading works too, but they don't seem to play nice together.

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
{
    GL2 gl  = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    render.mutate();
    eval.display();     //display images
    drawTexture(gl, loader.getTexture());
    gl.glFlush();       //glFinish() doesn't work either

    eval.evaluate();    //read images
}
```

What seems to happen is that eval.evaluate() is called before the output is actually on screen. This results in the evaluate function just reading empty images.

I always assumed that when glFlush() is called, everything is output to the screen, but apparently not.

So is there a way to force the program to somehow wait for the output to appear on screen before continuing with the reading?

Also, it's not possible to get the bytebuffer directly from the images, because one of the images is not really an image but rather a collection of triangles drawn with openGL.

Comment: You're thinking of `glFinish`, not `glFlush`. Not that it matters; AFAIK all GL reading commands should wait for every command that may change its output to execute.

Comment: Neither `glFlush (...)` nor `glFinish (...)` have anything to do with whether or not your drawbuffer is ***displayed***. They only control GL's execution. To display something requires interaction with the window system; in a double-buffered framebuffer, the window system will not change the displayed image until you swap front/back buffers. You need VSYNC + double buffering to wait until an image has actually "appeared," and both of those things are outside the scope of GL.

Comment: I was thinking, would it be possible to do reading part in a different thread? So the images would be displayed on screen and in a another thread the screen output would be read and evaluated, after which the image would be manipulated and the output changed. The only problem I see is that sharing the GL instance between threads would be difficult. Opinions?

Comment: I have to ask the question: Why do you want to wait for the image to be displayed on screen in the first place? If you are reading the image back using GL that should not be a requirement, but if you are capturing the screen using something else it could be understandable.

Comment: Yes, use `glReadPixels()` to read back your image. You won't even need a `glFlush()` for that to work. It sounds like you're trying to read the window content from the screen? I predict that you'll be in for a lot of (self inflicted) pain if you're trying to get that to work robustly, and across various platforms.

Comment: Well, I'm creating a java implantation of http://alteredqualia.com/visualization/evolve/ so what I need to do is: Mutate the evolving image, draw it on screen, read the pixeldata of the evolved image, calculate the fitness of the evolved image and possibly replace the best image with the new one. I originally did use glReadpixels, but it was so ridiculously slow that calling it in every display loop absolutely wrecked performance. So, I switched to using GLReadBufferUtil, which is quite a lot faster.

Comment: You should consider doing asynchronous read-back with PBOs.

Comment: Quick and dirty solution would be to first call `eval.evaluate();` and then your rendering code. That way you should get finished image from previous render loop.